# How did my reputation go up?

Tags: support, reputation

So far today, I have earned 62 reputation . But all I did today was [ask a question that has a score of -2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73236809). This confuses me a lot. How did I get this reputation? None of my other questions have changed score, and as far as I know, I earned 2 reputation for accepting an answer to my post.

Comment: You can +10 for each upvote and -2 for each downvote.

Comment: ( 8 upvotes * +10 ) + ( 10 downvotes * -2) + ( 1 accept * +2) = 80 - 20 + 2 = 62

Comment: Your question has 10 downvotes and 8 upvotes. So in total thats 8 upvotes x 10 reputation, which is 80 reputation. Then subtract 10 downvotes x 2 reputation. You now get 60 reputation. Add 2 reputation for accepting an answer, you now have 62 reputation, which is the expected amount.

Comment: you can *audit* your reputation by checking its *history*: from your user page (click the reputation numbers on top right [main site, not here]) -> `Activity` -> `Reputation`; or just click https://stackoverflow.com/users/11072709/caleb-liu?tab=reputation (probably the same page used to gather information given in previous comments)